# High CPU utilization when uploading a file

Tags: vapor

This code uses 99-100% CPU:

```
drop.post("upload") { request in
    guard let file = request.multipart?["zip"]?.file, let name = file.name else {
        throw Abort.badRequest
    }

    try Data(bytes: file.data).write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/tmp/\(name)"))
    return "OK"
}
```

How to optimize this task?

Comment: I think you should add this as an issue in Vapor's Github repository. On the other hand, try use Xcode instruments.

Answer (score 0):

This is a confirmed bug. Track the progress here: https://github.com/vapor/vapor/issues/734

Until then, you can use the raw `request.body` as a workaround for accessing uploaded files.